# Jquery stop/start mousemove on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I am trying to stop a `mousemove` on `$("body").click` then when it is clicked again I want the mousemove to reactivate again. I cant seem to construct an if statement that works

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".chimp").mousemove(function(e) {
        $('.chimp').css({
            'top': e.clientY - 20,
            'left': e.clientX - 20
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Kindly provide a fiddle now currently how it is working

Comment: Close the document function `});`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var bodyClickCount = 0; // Default to not clicked

    $(".chimp").mousemove(function(e) {
        if (bodyClickCount % 2) { // Check if body is clicked
            $('.chimp').css({
                'top': e.clientY - 20,
                'left': e.clientX - 20
            });
        }
    });

    $(document.body).on('click', function() {
        bodyClickCount++; // Increase the body click counter
    });
});
```